# DLL_PROCESS_DETACH некорректно отрабатывает WaitForSingleObject

Tags: c++, dll

Пишу DLL.

Вызываю 1-ю функцию, внутри неё я создаю thread:

```
hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThreadFunction, ...);
```

Хочу завершить thread, вызываю 2-ю функцию:

```
StopMyThread(hThread); //моя фукнция
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(hThread);
```

Всё отрабатывает корректно.

Теперь я хочу закрыть thread, если программа, которая использует dll, вызовет FreeLibrary. Для этого в dllmain обрабатываю DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. Пишу тот же код, что и для 2-ой функции, но зависает на WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE).

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Далеко не все функции можно безопасно вызывать внутри `DllMain`. Если правило нарушено может случиться dead-lock, как раз Ваш случай.

Более подробно можно почитать об этом на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx#general_best_practices).

Comment: И каким образом корректно завершать thread? Не подскажите?

Comment: @sitev_ru делать это вне `DllMain`.

Comment: А как мне тогда корректно обработать FreeLibrary?

Comment: @sitev_ru, возможно Вам поможет [FreeLibraryAndExitThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683153(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: При вызове DLLMain вызывается системная критическая секция, которая так же используется в таких функциях как: 
WaitForSingleObject и других. Заменил WaitForSingleObject на самописную - всё заработало!